# Special characters in PHP scripts stops execution

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am importing employee data from .csv file as bulk operation. There is many fields like First name, Last Name, Email, Contact No, Address etc.

Email field in database is Index/Unique. So i have put validation over it.

But my question is when certain rows contains special characters like matinées@fauts.net or débutante@peured.info [focus **é**].

This will stops php script execution unexpectedly without error log. I have also go through Apache Error Log/PHP Error Log but there is no errors. Please help me to prevent this.

I have also tried to set character encoding scheme to UTF-8 or Westorn-ISO-800 etc, but this will not work.

Code snippet:

```
`                   $firstname = $sd[0];
                    if ($firstname != '' || !empty($firstname)) {

                        $lastname = $sd[1];
                        $email = $sd[2];
                        if ($sd[3] != '' && $sd[3] != NULL) {                                
                            $password = md5( $sd[3]);
                        }
                        $contactno = $sd[4];
                        $internalextension = $sd[5];
                        $companyid = $this->session->userdata('companyid');

                        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                            return array("status" => FALSE, "message" => "Error while Importing Employee. Please Check Your .csv "
                                . "file; <br/> Your file contains Invalid Email Id at Line number" . ($count + 1) . ". Email: $email");
                        } else {

                            if ($count != 500) {

                                $query = $query . "(NULL, '" . $firstname . "', '" . $lastname . "', '" . $email . "', "
                                        . "'" . $password . "', '" . $salt . "', 1, '" . $contactno . "',"
                                        . "'" . $internalextension . "', 4, " . $companyid . ", '" . my_datenow() . "'),";
                            } else {

                                $query = $query . "(NULL, '" . $firstname . "', '" . $lastname . "', '" . $email . "', "
                                        . "'" . $password . "', '" . $salt . "', 1, '" . $contactno . "',"
                                        . "'" . $internalextension . "', 4, " . $companyid . ", '" . my_datenow() . "');";
                                echo $query;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        return array("status" => FALSE, "message" => "Error while Importing Employee. Please Check Your .csv file; First Name should not be blank.");
                    }`
```

Comment: Also set `Collation` to `utf8_general_ci` for email fled in database

Comment: Before executing database operation whole at once this will happen. I mean first preparing query and execute whole at once. But error occurs during preparing query.

Comment: can you post your prepare statemant

Comment: that is the issue statement is not completed due to unexpected error at line of this types of characters occurrences. E.g. if char occur at line 245 then Insert query will prepare for first 244 records only and  then stops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use htmlspecialchars() before assigning value to variable for example

```
$firstname = htmlspecialchars($sd[0]);
```

htmlspecialchars — Convert special characters to HTML entities
reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Yes you are right but htmlspecialchars() function convert special charcters to html display entity only as i know, and storing this converted email in database will create problem in future to login with email. This will not be the case.

Comment: I think then you can use mysql_real_escape_string() function to escape the characters that might conflict with the query. for example while creating query use mysql_real_escape_string($email). give it a try